# AJAX Trigger other things to update on click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I have been adding `UpdatePanels` to my application around the objects that I just want to update.

**Example**, When I click a button I want a `ListBox` to update. I would wrap the `UpdatePanel` around the list box in the html, but when I do this my design goes all over the place.

I am not sure If I'm using AJAX the correct way, as I have seen people adding `Triggers` but don't know how and where to use them, here is an example of my code:

```
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lst_AdminExistingDepartments" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Acceptance"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Acceptance"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Acceptance"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Acceptance"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Acceptance"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Acceptance"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Acceptance"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:ListBox>
                </div>

                <div class="AddEditUpdateDepartment">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_AdminAddEditUpdateDepartments" runat="server" Text="Modify Departments" />

                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_AdminAddDepartment" runat="server" Text="Add Department" />
                    <input id="txt_AddDepartment" runat="server" type="text" class="aclass" />
                    <input id="btn_AddDepartment" runat="server" type="button" class="ButtonAdminPage" value="Add" onserverclick="btn_AddDepartment_ServerClick" />
```

**Here is a  `ListBox` and also a  `Textbox` and a  `Button`. When they click that  `Button` I would want the  `ListBox` to update with the record entered in the  `TextBox` using AJAX?**

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level you need to place the `UpdatePanel` around all controls being affected by the action. So you need the `List`, `TextBox` and `Button` all inside the `UpdatePanel`.

Following on from that you have more advanced scenarios where you can have `Triggers` and multiple `UpdatePanels` etc. However, it would be best to start with something simple (i.e. everything you need in one `UpdatePanel` and advance from there.

Comment: As stated in my question when I do wrap around the controls all the design aspects messes up and moves all over the place. These controls are at to different sections of the page this is just an example. I wouldn't be able to wrap the updatepanel around them both as there would be basically all my code in the updatepanel.

Comment: Well, that is because you will have another `div` that you need to deal with. Ultimately that is how it works. It is probably easier to fix the CSS than re-write everything in AJAX proper if you are unsure of all the principles? This is the trade off when using things out of the box. It shouldn't be hard to fix the CSS though?

Comment: So there isn't a way to trigger the list box to update when the button is clicked?

Comment: Triggers allow you to control other `UpdatePanels` but the controls need to be in `UpdatePanels`. If they are outside then they won't be AJEX-ified. Therefore, back to your formatting issue.